# Invalid command using stats in gnuplot

Tags: statistics, gnuplot, invalid-argument

so I'm fairly new to gnuplot and I'm stumped by an invaild command error I get when I try to use stats on a file in gnuplot.

The command in question:

```
gnuplot> stats "file.dat" using 1
stats "file.dat" using 1
         ^
         invalid command
```

The file works just fine with the plot command, as in:

```
gnuplot> plot "file.dat" using 1 with lines
plot "file.dat" using 1 with lines
```

The data file file.dat looks like this:

```
125.48  262.31
0.85    215.18
0.85    175.29
0.85    132.11
0.85    78.72
0.74    33.92
0.74    15.98
0.28    9.63
0.28    7.28
0.28    6.24
0.10    5.76
0.10    5.08
0.01    5.02
0.01    4.93
0.01    4.77
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stats` command is available only since version 4.6.0. In previous versions it is possible to access some data information only after plotting. That includes e.g. the exact data ranges, which are available through the variables `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN`, `GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX` etc. Use

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1
show variables all
```

To see the available variables. Then you can do something like

```
plot 'file.dat' using 1
# do something with GPVAL_*
replot
```

Comment: Solved. The Mint Software Manager gave me version 4.4. Installed version 4.6 and stats works just fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, GPVAL_* was a good alternative, thanks for the suggestion, but I didn't get all the functionality there I was hoping for. Stats seems to offer that.